# MYSQL - failed to acquire exclusive database access

Tags: php, mysql

Getting the error sporadically:

"Failed to acquire exclusive database access"

in my PHP application on the live server.

Can't see anything in the logs.

Checked the server settings and:
max_connections: 100
max_user_connections: 0

As I understand from the documentation the 0 means no limit and is the default.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The word "exclusive" implies that you are trying to do something which requires locking the table, which the script cannot do. Which storage engine are you using? What is the line of PHP code that produces the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to see an error similar to this all the time in Access but haven't seen it with MySQL before. I don't think your `max_user_connections` is the problem because the key word in that error message is "exclusive" meaning you need to have the ONLY access to a table.

My guess would be it's something with InnoDB and its locking mechanism. If you don't require transaction safe records, try switching your table to MyISAM and see if the error persists.

Take a look here for InnoDB locking: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Comment: have found the cause, which was a php line requesting exclusive lock on a particular table in question.  Have removed this request as it's unnecessary but this is still useful information, thanks.